# Fabric - Handle error when mirror not available

Tags: python, fabric

My fabric script installs AWS Systems Manager from a mirror. Right now it fails if the mirror is not available.
Is there a way to handle this situation? I would love to supply additional mirrors and have it try each until successful. How can I add that?

```
def ssm_install():
try:
    is_running = sudo('status amazon-ssm-agent', warn_only=True)
    if "start/running" in is_running:
        sys.exit()
    else:
        run('mkdir -p /tmp/ssm')
        run('cd /tmp/ssm')
        sudo('yum install -y https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads-windows/SSMAgent/latest/linux_amd64/amazon-ssm-agent.rpm')
        sys.exit()
except NetworkError:
    print "Can't connect to this host"
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: Yes. It can, but it doesn't make sense. Just add another exception for the error type

Comment: Or put it all in a loop where a successful run breaks the loop and unsuccessful run continues the loop